# About to release a free game on Google Play Store, any legal considerations I should take into account?

Tags: legal

I will release in the next few weeks a small free game on the Google Play Store. I was wondering if there was any important legal aspects I should consider before release.

Here's a few infos:

- I'm doing this alone.
- There's no code/graphic assets/gameplay concepts I would like to protect in particular. I don't have any issues with people copying something from my game.
- I'm not sure right now, but maybe I'll add the possibility to make a small donation (so there will be IAP in a sense).
- I'm using a music track from http://opengameart.org/. The author has specified that it wasn't necessary to credit him, though I would like to.

Comment: I suggest you consult with a lawyer. And that you take a look at this: [Common legal pitfalls for GameDevs](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=49u8B7Uw7qU).

Comment: It actually depends on the license associated with whatever assets you use from other source.

Comment: I only use the music I mentioned in my question.

Comment: _"There's no code/graphic assets/gameplay concepts I would like to protect in particular. I don't have any issues with people copying something from my game."_ This allows ppl to copy your game. If they decide to actually copy the game, make a small tweak and add in-app purchase, and invest their time and money on marketing, they could be making a lot of money for little effort. Don't release a game without copyright.

Comment: While a good question, it's a not a good question for this site. This would be more suitable for a forum or other site where people can provide various inputs that would be compiled into a list.